# alphabetically sort elements in a List

Tags: java

I have a `Shape` class and in this class there is a method called `getRepr()` that can get a `char` representation of a shape. For example,

```
ShapeA.getRepr() ->'a' 
ShapeB.getRepr() ->'b'
ShapeC.getRepr() ->'c'
```

Now I have an `ArrayList` that stores several shapes including `ShapeE`, `ShapeA`, `ShapeD`, `ShapeC`, and `ShapeB`.

The question is how can I use `Collections.sort()` to **alphabetically** rearrange these shapes in the `ArrayList` according to their `char` representations?

The expected result in this `ArrayList` after sorting should be `ShapeA`, `ShapeB`, `ShapeC`, `ShapeD`, `ShapeE`.

Or is there a way to reach this purpose without `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: Are `ShapeA`...`ShapeE` subclasses of class `Shape`?

Comment: @jadhachem they are all shape type

Answer (score 5):

you need to implement Comparable interface in your SuperClass

```
public class MyClassSuperClass implements Comparable<MyClassSuperClass>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClassSuperClass o) {
        return this.getRepr().compareTo(o.getRepr());
    }


}
```

Then you can just call the .sort method on your collection

1. if obj a>b the compareTo shall return a value > 0
2. if obj a

   if obj a == b the compareTo shall return 0

> For the mathematically inclined, the relation that defines the natural
>   ordering on a given class C is:
>
> ```
>    {(x, y) such that x.compareTo(y) <= 0}.   The quotient for this total order is:
>    {(x, y) such that x.compareTo(y) == 0}.   It follows immediately from the contract for compareTo that the quotient is an
> ```
>
> equivalence relation on C, and that the natural ordering is a total
>   order on C. When we say that a class's natural ordering is consistent
>   with equals, we mean that the quotient for the natural ordering is the
>   equivalence relation defined by the class's equals(Object) method:
>        {(x, y) such that x.equals(y)}.

for more information please check this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here:
[Alphabetically Sort a Java Collection based upon the 'toString' value of its member items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554769/alphabetically-sort-a-java-collection-based-upon-the-tostring-value-of-its-mem)

```
Collections.sort(list,
             new Comparator<String>()
             {
                 public int compare(String s1, String s2)
                 {
                     return s1.compareTo(s2);
                 }        
             });
```

Comment: Note that this just compares two Strings (not two Shapes) by their natural ordering, for which you don't actually need a custom Comparator (you can just do `Collections.sort(list)` and get the same result).

Comment: @yshavit is right here. And you don't need a custom `Comparator`, because your current type `String` already implements the `Comparable` interface, so it will take care about comparing itself with another String instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Comparable/Comparator to achieve this, check this link for detailed info  [Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)